# Passed String not being treated as String

Tags: java, string, url

I have a Java program that is watching a folder using Java's nio file watcher. When something is created in that folder, it gets the name of that file and using `FileInputStream InputStreamReader` it sets the contents to a String. The String is then passed to a class that uses this String as the parameters for printing a report. The report server is returning an error, saying:

> no protocol:
>   java.io.InputStreamReader@dda25b?timezone=America/New_York&vgen=1377628109&cmd=get_pg&page=1&viewer=java2

It would seem that it doesn't like the part of the String because Java is treating it as some kind of command instead of a String, changing what it says. I'm sure there is a straightforward solution, but I am unsure of how to phrase it. The String looks like this:

> serverURL:port/?report=repo:reportname&datasource=datasource&prompt0=Date(2014,1,2)

CODE:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.nio.file.*;
import static java.nio.file.StandardWatchEventKinds.*;

public class watching {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
        String dirToWatch = "\\\\DIRECTORY\\PATH\\HERE\\";
            WatchService watcher = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();
            Path logDir = Paths.get(dirToWatch);
            logDir.register(watcher, ENTRY_CREATE);
            while (true) {
                WatchKey key = watcher.take();
                for (WatchEvent<?> event : key.pollEvents()) {
                    WatchEvent.Kind<?> kind = event.kind();

                if (kind == ENTRY_CREATE) {
                    WatchEvent<Path> ev = (WatchEvent<Path>) event;
                    Path filename = ev.context();
                    String thisfile = filename.toString();
                    //System.out.printf("%s was created in log dir.", filename.getFileName());
                    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(dirToWatch+thisfile);
                    InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(fis, "UTF-8");
                    String inetargs = in.toString();
                    inetprint printer = new inetprint (inetargs);

                }
            }

            key.reset();
        }
    } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Post your code. `java.io.InputStreamReader@dda25b` is the result of un-overriden `Object#toString()` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line "inetargs = in.toString()" is the problem. It looks like you think that will read the contents of the file into a string, but it will do nothing of the sort! You must use its read() methods to read the file contents.

Comment: OH, I see what you're saying. That was sloppy of me. i

Comment: I read the lines as you said and the String is definitely passed in. However, as I suspected, the String is still being interpreted as more than just a String.

no protocol: serveraddress:port/?report=reportname&datasource=datasource&prompt0=Date%282014%2c1%2c2%29&timezone=America/New_York&vgen=1377696115&cmd=get_pg&page=1&viewer=java2

The Date should look like what I posted above. Any ideas on that?

Comment: The date looks OK -- it's "URL encoded", which is how some special characters need to be treated in a URL. But as the error message says, there's no *protocol* -- it doesn't say "http://" or "https://" or "ftp://" or anything like that at the beginning. Whatever the "inetprint" class is doing with that URL, it wants a fully-formed URL, which includes the protocol part at the beginning.